# How to fill picker in react native from array

Tags: arrays, react-native

i want to fill a picker items from array .. this array store data from local storage and i want to display this data on picker

this is my function that retrieve data from local storage

```
async getElementsInLocalStorage() {
 try{    
    let x = [];
    let all_keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();

    for(i = 1; i <= all_keys.length;i++ ){
        let converter =  JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('one_person'+i));
        x[i] = converter.first_name + ' ' + converter.last_name;                  
    }

    this.setState({all_options: x, data: x,});
 } catch(error){
   alert(error)
 }
}
```

And this is my constructor

```
constructor(){
    super();   
    this.state = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name : '',
        all_options : [],    
    };
    data = [];
}
```

And this is my Picker

```
 <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.selected} >
       {this.state.data.map((value)=><Picker.Item label={value} value={value}/>)} 
 </Picker>
```

when type `data` only in picker picker not filled but when type `this.state.data`
[this is error return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOek4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `data` as a seperate variable in constructor. But after fetching data you are considering `data` as a state variable.

Just declare `data` inside state, and that might solve your issue.

```
constructor(){
    super();   
    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name : '',
      all_options : [],   
      data:[] 
    };
}
```

Comment: i tried like you but this error return in this photo
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501095378150

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. What I did is

Moved data inside state and added conditional check before doing .map

```
constructor(){
    super();   
    this.state = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name : '',
        all_options : [], 
        data = []
    };
}
```

And this is my Picker

```
<Picker selectedValue = {this.state.selected} >
       {this.state.data && this.state.data.map(value=> (<Picker.Item label={value} value={value}/>))} 
 </Picker>
```

Comment: change `data = [];` to `data: []`

Comment: @Think-Twice 
it doesn't work and give me same error
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501095378150

Comment: WHAT is the error I am not able to see that in the link u shared

Comment: You need to share the component code. The code you shared isnt the defected one