# How can I execute more than one thing onDateChange react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this date piker and I want to execute function manage when `onDateChange`  that change the date to selected date it execute the function manage but it give me that

> can't find variable date

Here is my code:

```
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
     date:'',
    };
      }


manage = () => {
 this.setState({date:date})
  const  url='myIP/api/timeApi';
axios.post(url,{date})
.then(resp =>alert('done'))
.catch(err => alert(err));
}

            <DatePicker
               date={this.state.date}
                mode="date"
                format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                }}
                onDateChange={this.manage.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do binding directly in render instead always do it in constructor. You know what happens if you directly do binding in rende, every time your component renders it will create a new function in Webpack bundled file. But if you do that constructor then it gets created only once because constructor gets called only once per component

Regarding your issue the onDataChange prop returns the date so you need to get the date like below

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.manage = this.manage.bind(this);
 }

 manage = date => {
   this.setState({date:date})
   const  url='myIP/api/timeApi';
   axios.post(url,{date})
   .then(resp =>alert('done'))
   .catch(err => alert(err));
 }

 <DatePicker
           date={this.state.date}
            mode="date"
            format="DD/MM/YYYY"
            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
            }}
            onDateChange={this.manage}
```

Comment: Np. You can also upvote my answer when you accept it.

Comment: can you help in this issue  ??   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511673/how-to-fill-picker-in-react-native-from-array

Comment: Answered. Please give a try